# Pros and Cons of embedding Yaws web server within ejabberd server

Tags: erlang, webserver, ejabberd, yaws

I am working on a instance messaging app, I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of embedding yaws web server within ejabberd server, does it a right thing to embed yaws within ejabberd for a instance messaging app?

Comment: Without a little more information its hard to say if there would be anything *wrong* with it. I would rather ask why ejabbered is the sole focus of your system -- if you require yaws at all then you're doing more that *just* instant messaging, and if you're not talking to external XMPP clients it might be easier to just write have yaws serve a page and route messages over websockets. Ejabbered is a big mess because XMPP is a big mess -- think about what your actual requirements are and whether you're pulling in a lot of unneeded complexity before even writing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific advantage in embedding Yaws within. If you need Yaws, this is to serve web pages / web content. You should keep ejabberd as is and unmodified and run a separate service in the tech of your choice for the web part.
That way, your architecture will be simpler and more flexible.

Please, note that ejabberd is already handling XMPP over HTTP (Bosh and Websocket). You do not need a separate service for that.

Comment: @ Mickael, I want to upload media files(videos, audio, images and docs) upto 1 GB does ejabberd HTTP module support uploading files to this extent?

Comment: File upload / transfer are not supposed to be made to ejabberd. XMPP should be use for signalling of transfers. You should use a separate service for handling large HTTP file in my opinion, not embed that into ejabberd.

Comment: It can be right, but I see no reason to embed that transfer service into ejabberd itself.